# When are Morocco desert camel excursions available?

Tags: morocco, animal-riding, deserts

I had heard that the desert excursions (around Merzouga) only run during the cooler months of the year (November to February). But I've looked at a few sites and I haven't found anything that confirms this. Can someone please verify this with a reliable source?

---

**Update:** I picked up a copy of [Rough Guide to Morocco](http://www.roughguides.com/destinations/africa/morocco/southern-oases-routes/ziz-tafilalt/merzouga-erg-chebbi/camel-rides-around-merzouga/) and it states

> Note, too, that the longer multi-day trips stop operating after
>   February, after which time it just gets too hot.

Yet this contradicts what Karlson has posted, along with the fact that the websites for the excursions don't make any mention of this.

Comment: Can you post the link of the Rough Guide to Morocco?

Comment: @Karlson It's a hard copy, but the quote it direct

Comment: I found the link.  Updated an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not the case and while no site states that tours run year round you could find references on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g293730-d480337-r88406161-Moroccan_Sahara-Morocco.html) where a user documents his trip to Sahara in June and another referring to a similar tour in September.

And while tours might be suggested for November through February because the temperatures in the winter might be more comfortable for people from northerly climates it doesn't mean that people stop living in the desert and thus tours aren't likely to stop.

**Update**

Specific comments by various users from [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293734-i9196-k5062861-Camel_trek_in_June_in_Morocco-Marrakech_Marrakech_Tensift_El_Haouz_Region.html) about Sahara Trip in June.  And just to put another nail in that coffin [Camel Safari in Morocco in June, July, and August](http://www.responsibletravel.com/holiday/5707/budget-camel-safari-in-morocco)

Comment: Thanks Karlson. But I just want to point out that the link (last line, second paragraph) only confirms what I quoted, no?  Not that it matters, just saying.

Comment: @MarkE All it confirms that they have claimed it.  The validity of such a claim is basically disproved with reports of people who have taken tours to the availability of the tours for purchase.  There is a bunch of other sites other then the one they list (which is poorly done IMHO) that allow you to book tours with no limitation on season, e.g.  http://www.cameltrekking.com

Answer (score 5):

Desert tours in Morocco run year round. As a tour operator in Morocco we organize tours to Erg Chebbi sand dunes by Merzouga anytime of the year, all summer and even during Ramadan.

But we discourage clients coming to Erg Chegaga sand dunes by M'hamid. Because these sand dunes are in complete wilderness, over 1 hour off road driving though the desert and the temperatures are just to hot to hide anywhere.

Erg Chebbi has many hotels built on the outskirts and even nearest hospital is not too far. The camel treks start late afternoon before sunset when the heat is not that bad and the same in the morning, you depart early before the sun gets too strong.

Comment: Actual information and links to your site might be helpful but great info anyway